# better way to debug instances from require

Tags: node.js, debugging

Take the following piece of code

```
var runner = require('./generationRunner.js');
```

When debugging runner='undefined' and that is because code inside the file is blowing up. However, when this happens require returns undefined rather than the instance and also not throwing an exception. This behavior makes it hard at times to debug and fix the bad code. What is the better approach to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

when the code in the required file breaks usally this error would bubble up causing in a crash of the program.
actually it is recommended way of handling that issue because your program from this point on is in an undefined state that will (or will not) cause unexpected behaviour.

the best way would be to trace down why a crash in the required file does not bubble up and to tackle this issue.

Comment: It think I have pinned this behavior to syntax errors inside the required file. It is disappointing that no exception is being bubbled up. Something like syntax error at line xx.yy would be very helpful.

Comment: it *should* throw that exception, can you try doing a `process.on('uncaughtException', function(error) { console.log(error); })`? this possibly expose the error

Comment: I will try that a little later buy I did wrap the require line in a try catch and the catch was never hitting therefore no exception was bubbled.